# Themes iniPhone

Tags: iphone, tags

I wanted to change my iPhone app appearence by using Leather theme,but I don't know how to install the theme to xcode and use them.Please help me by explaining the steps for it.

Comment: You have to manage that in your application

Answer (score 2):

Please make clear that if you want to implement a leather theme only or implement the leather theme in addition to your original appearance

If you want to implement only the leather theme then you can easily maintain it by changing the images. Otherwise you have to set all the images in code and have to choose them according to the selected theme.